# CSS - How to match class (one dynamic and one static) between two elements

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to tie a css rule between my body and a subsequent div element. Using wordpress, my body element has classes defined to itself based on what page is loaded. I'm trying to implement a styling that will essentially check if the classe author- is present (`body.author-<*>`), then find the div having the same class name and implement a specific styling.

I can't use any interal wordpress function as the list containing the said div (list of authors) is dynamically set in my code.

Aswell, I was hoping to avoid using javascript as I'd like to limit the scope of this change to CSS if possible.

Also, as there's many users listed in my list, specifying a static css rule for each user, such as `body.author-user1 div.author-user1{}...` would be annoying to maintain as new authors could be added later and I'd want to limit any future code change to purely html.

Is this possible with only css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an advanced css selector

```
body[class^="author"] {  }
```

To find all the bodys whose classes start with author and then do the same for the div

```
body[class^="author"] div[class^="author"] {  }
```

however I dont know about ie compatibility for anything lower than ie8.

Comment: Problem with advanced css selector is that i not only need to check that both elements have a class starting with author or author-, but each author div will have a unique class name, such as author-user1, author-user2... It's too bad there's not way to a logic check between two attribute between two elements in css...

Comment: true. you could use a bit of jQuery to find the div whose class equals the body and add an 'active' class to it. would only be a line or so. If thats an option it would look something like 
`var bodyClass= $(body).attr('class');
jQuery(div[class^="author-"]).filter('.'+bodyClass).addClass('active');`
might need tweaked a little as i haven't tested it.

Comment: Yup very true. I'm just worried about the delay it would case at rendering... Probably minimal, but worth checking.

Comment: By pulling in the divs whose class only start with author and filtering from there I attempted to minimize the time it would take. The rendering delay would not be noticeable unless the computer used to render the site was very old

Comment: `bodyClass= $(body).attr('class');`
Wouldn't this line essentially be extracting all the classes? And by doing so your second line would be filtering on all classes, although syntaxically incorrect (as its a concatonation between "." and an array)?

Comment: If the body has multiple classes then yes that wouldnt work as written. It may require a regex to find the array item that starts with 'author-' which would not be best used in jQuery. It would most likely be easier to add the static class in php.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would set both a body class AND the inside class to `author-#`. It seems like it would make the most sense to just add a numbered ID to one of them (considering how unique of a value it is), and then just control that element directly through CSS.

I'm not sure if this still pertains to your question, but to do the "check" to see if the *author-* prefix is in your class, just use an [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) like so:

```
body[class|=author] { ... }
```

Comment: The importance to having the class defined in both body and user div is that when the user visits the author's page in wordpress (listing all of his or her posts), I want this username or profile to be highlighted from the list. The reason I'm using the username vs. a user id is that wordpress already has a built-in function that already defines a class based on the username (as opposed to the user id). Adding new authors to the list will be alot more comprehensive if its based on the username of the author versus an arbitrary number.

Comment: Ah, I now understand what it is you're looking for. You can't really achieve what you're looking for using CSS, you'd probably be better manipulating the PHP to assign an additional class on the `<div>` you are looking to highlight.

Comment: Oh good point! Never thought of investigating PHP. It might be simpler to set a .highlight class directly to the div, as long as the scoping through the wordpress php pages allows it. Thanks.